# Python dict with timer entry

Tags: python, dictionary, timer

I want to create a dict having as an entry a timer. When the entry timer times-out, a function should be called to make some treatment on that entry. e.g.:

```
dict = [key, timer]
if timer == 0
    f(key, timer)
```

Is there any method to do it.
Thanks alot for your help.
regards,
Karim

Answer (score 2):

You could make all your values [timer objects](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html#timer-objects) which will fire after a given amount of time. This will make your program rely on the threading module though.

Alternatively, you could have a single "timer thread" that goes through the all the elements in the dictionary once in a while and decrements the counts. If it finds that an element has reduced to zero, it should call a callback.

If your dictionary is dependent on "number of times accessed" rather than on actual *time*, you should maybe think about capturing the access calls and using those to increment and decrement the counts rather than using threads (i.e. by redifining or wrapping `__setitem__` and `__getitem__`).

Answer (score 1):

@karim: You should definitely look at event-driven libraries such as [Gevent](http://gevent.org), or [Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/). Gevent, for example, has something like `gevent.spawn_later(seconds, function, *args, **kwargs)` which, I think, suits your need pretty close. You can even spawn functions out of order.

For example:

```
gevent.spawn_later(5, f1)
gevent.spawn_later(3, f2)
```

And `f2` will be executed 3 seconds later, then `f1` 2 seconds after that.